# How to convert object keys to upper case

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

I would like to transform lowercase key to uppercase key. But finding my try not works.

what would be the correct approach?

here is my try:

```js
var obj = {
  name: "new name",
  age: 33
}

const x = Object.assign({}, obj);

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(x)) {
  key = key.toUpperCase();
}


console.log(x);
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z9bnjcyf/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With

```
key = key.toUpperCase();
```

Reassigning a variable will almost never do anything on its own (even if `key` was reassignable) - you need to explicitly to mutate the existing object:

```js
var obj = {
  name: "new name",
  age: 33
}

const x = {};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  x[key.toUpperCase()] = value;
}
console.log(x);
```

You could also use `reduce`, to avoid the *external* mutation of `x`:

```js
var obj = {
  name: "new name",
  age: 33
}

const x = Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [key, value]) => {
  a[key.toUpperCase()] = value;
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(x);
```

Comment: How about array of object like : `var obj = [{
 name:"new name",
  age:33
}, {
 name:"new ccc",
  age:34
}]`

Comment: Use `.map`, and have the mapper function take in the item being iterated over as `obj`, and return `x`